# How can I input the same number multiple times on an HTML page and within code?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very basic question regarding an HTML page.  I would like to create a template for an HTML webpage and on that page I need to reference a number (property ID) multiple times on the actual web page and in the code to link to image sources.  I would like to be able to type the property ID once into the template code and that code will be populated into all the places I need it for the page to display properly vs having to type the 5-8 digit number over and over and over.

Below is a basic example of the template page - instead of having to write property ID 123456 multiple times, I would like to be able to write it once into the template or JS and then have it populated into the areas where the property ID needs to repeat.  The property ID will also be a folder containing images for the webpage.  Each folder will contain 1-25 images named 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg and so on so I'll need to be able to use the property ID to be a part of the source code.  Currently the template looks like this...

```
<html>
<body>
<p>You are viewing Property #123456</p>
<img src="123456/1.jpg">
<img src="123456/2.jpg">
<img src="123456/3.jpg">
<img src="123456/4.jpg">
<p>Would you like more information regarding Property #123456?</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to be able to quickly make new pages using a template without needing to copy & paste the property ID into each page multiple times.

I envision something like this...

```
<html>
<body>
<p>You are viewing Property #<span class="propID"></span></p>
<img src="******/1.jpg">
<img src="******/2.jpg">
<img src="******/3.jpg">
<img src="******/4.jpg">
<p>Would you like more information regarding Property #<span class="propID">?</p>
</body>
</html>
```

With the ***** in the img src referencing the propID somehow using JS but I do not know how to do this.

What's the best/easiest way to go about doing this?
TIA

Comment: Please edit your question and add in your JS code that demonstrates your best attempt to resolve this yourself.

Comment: use a lib like vue then its trivial

Comment: @devlincarnate can this be achieved by `SQL` or have to use `JavaScript` ,like showing info like phone number and names and other data with single html where as all other tabs are created with just change in data

Comment: The OP tagged the question as JavaScript so I'm assuming that's the direction the OP is taking.  As it stands, the question lacks clear definition, which is why we need to see the OP's code segment that shows us the best attempt at resolving this.

Comment: @devlincarnate I am asking in general not in question context like when there is data like name, phone no. ..... and have make same web pages with different names and phone number..... than we use `SQL` or `JavaScript`

Comment: I do not have a best attempt at solving this besides using JS and establishing a variable on the page as propID but it only populates once and the other instances are empty.

Comment: How are you generating the content? If using a backend language, I'd use a variable to number them with that. Or you could wrap each group in, for example, `<div class='property'></div>` Then iterate through all the divs with class="property" and insert your iterators that way.

Comment: @Rana : yes, it's very common to load data from a database to a web form.  You'll need a server-side language to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use an element (such as `<span>`) to display your number. Consider following a JS tutorial (such as at [w3schools.com](https://w3schools.com)) to learn more about manipulating HTML with JavaScript.

```js
const property_number = 42;
elements = document.getElementsByClassName("property-number");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
  elements[i].innerText = property_number;
document.getElementById("img1").src = property_number + "/image_1.jpg";
```

```html
You are viewing <span class="property-number"></span>
<img id="img1" />
```

Comment: what about the images? also `id="property-number"` can only be used once

Comment: Thank you for your response but the edited version is not working??

Answer (score 0):

Taken answer from [Imagifight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5224022/imagifight)

You have to just give array value to run the function

Used `for` loops and some basics , if need to know something from code or want to ask a doubt feel free to comment

```js
const property_number = ["12345", "35245", "45234"];
var mainCont = document.getElementsByClassName("mainContainer");

for (let i = 0; i < mainCont.length; i++) {

  var mainContId = mainCont[i].getElementsByTagName("SPAN")
  var mainContIdImg = mainCont[i].getElementsByTagName("IMG")

  for (let j = 0; j < mainContId.length; j++) {
    mainContId[j].innerHTML = property_number[i]
  }

  for (let k = 0; k < mainContIdImg.length; k++) {
    mainContIdImg[k].src = property_number[i] + k + "/image_1.jpg";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <p>You are viewing Property #<span class="propID"></span></p>
  <img src="" class="imgSrc">
  <img src="" class="imgSrc">
  <img src="" class="imgSrc">
  <p>Would you like more information regarding Property #<span class="propID"></span>?</p>
</div>

<div class="mainContainer">
  <p>You are viewing Property #<span class="propID"></span></p>
  <img src="" class="imgSrc">
  <img src="" class="imgSrc">
  <img src="" class="imgSrc">
  <p>Would you like more information regarding Property #<span class="propID"></span>?</p>
</div>

<div class="mainContainer">
  <p>You are viewing Property #<span class="propID"></span></p>
  <img src="" class="imgSrc">
  <img src="" class="imgSrc">
  <img src="" class="imgSrc">
  <p>Would you like more information regarding Property #<span class="propID"></span>?</p>
</div>
```

---

### Updated the answer for single productId only

**Here what I have done :**

1. Taken one time input of product Id in the `const property_number`
2. Get value from `.mainContainer` class in a variable `mainCont` which will be called later on
3. Now taken the value of all `span` tags (**Can also call by className  and it is also recommended**) and inputted the product ID to each `span` tag using the `for` loop.

> **Note to Remember:** product ID value is only valid inside the `.mainContainer` conatiner and it is not defined outside of it , so keep this in mind . As span tag is called from variable `mainCont`  which `.mainContainer`

4. Now all the `img` tag is taken from the `.mainContainer` class , whose `src` is entered using another `for` loop with `src` as `productID/(count of img tag).jpg` . So the first value is taken from variable `property_number` and second value is taken from the `j` value of `for` loop, as loop starts from `0` so added `1` to it.

> **Note to Remember :** As `https://` is not used so the domain will start from the folder where your `html` is saved . So try to start from `https://` and give the path else save images in the sub-folders where `html` is saved .

**That's all done :)**

```js
const property_number = 12345;
let mainCont = document.getElementsByClassName("mainContainer");

let mainContId = mainCont[0].getElementsByTagName("SPAN")
let mainContIdImg = mainCont[0].getElementsByTagName("IMG")

for (let i = 0; i < mainContId.length; i++) {
  mainContId[i].innerHTML = property_number
}

for (let j = 0; j < mainContIdImg.length; j++) {
  mainContIdImg[j].src = property_number + "/" + (j + 1) + ".jpg";
  document.getElementsByClassName("demo")[0].innerHTML = mainContIdImg[1].src;
  document.getElementsByClassName("demo1")[0].innerHTML = "https://hello/"+ property_number + "/" + (j + 1) + ".jpg";
   document.getElementsByClassName("demo2")[0].innerHTML = "F:/UsersPitures/Screenshoos"+ property_number + "/" + (j + 1) + ".jpg";
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <p>You are viewing Property #<span class="propID"></span></p>
  <img src="" class="imgSrc">
  <img src="" class="imgSrc">
  <img src="" class="imgSrc">
  <p>Would you like more information regarding Property #<span class="propID"></span>?</p>

  <p>My wish to write the productId 5 more times :</p>
  #<span class="propID"></span> #
  <span class="propID"></span> #
  <span class="propID"></span> #
  <span class="propID"></span> #
  <span class="propID"></span>
</div>
<hr>
<b>Below the line is of no use content but for understanding only</b>
<p>My wish to write the productId 5 more times but outside the class ".mainContainer":</p>
#<span class="propID"></span> #
<span class="propID"></span> #
<span class="propID"></span> #
<span class="propID"></span> #
<span class="propID"></span>

<p>The src of one of the image is :</p>
<div class="demo"></div>
<p>The src of any image with use of https:// </p>
<div class="demo1"></div>
<p>The src of any image with use of https:// </p>
<div class="demo2"></div>
```

Comment: As there can't be different images from a single `src` so you can just change the source by using some basic like every image `src` has productId included and an extra number like 0, 1, 2, 3...... added after the productId . Adding this change to the answer

Comment: Hi Rana - thanks for taking the time to answer my question but I think I made things more confusing and difficult than they needed to be.  I have edited my initial question - would you mind taking a look and seeing if there is an easier option than what you posted?